Moment of Inertia of cube about the axis along one of its diagonal
How can we find Moment of Inertia of a solid as well as a hollow cube about the axis passing from one of its diagonal?
I tried really hard solving it, please guide me to the solution.

You simply need to perform a rotation of coordinates of the standard inertia tensor. It's a one-step process.

Thank you @VincentThacker

Consider a reference frame centred at the center of the cube with axes perpendicular to the opposite faces. Evidently the three moments of inertia are here identical.
This means that the inertia tensor is proportional to the identity, so that every other triple of orthogonal axes centred at the center of the cube diagonalizes the tensor independently of its orientation. Furthermore each axis passing through the center has the same inertia moment.
In particular, all that holds for a triple made of the diagonals.
In summary, the moment you want to compute is exactly the same as computed for an axis perpendicular to two opposite faces and passing through the center of the cube. In this case the computation is easier.

I don't think a triple of diagonals is orthogonal?

They are necessary...

Thank you @ValterMoretti
